# Can't create a MongoDB document with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having a huge lot of issues working with MongoDB and Rails. I'm trying to make user feeds, but Rails keeps insulting me when I try to save the document. I have just NO idea what's happening and the documentation doesn't seem to help (as far as I know, I've done everything by the book).

Here are the relations I've done :

```
class Feed
  include Mongoid::Document
  field       :name,        :type => String
  field       :description, :type => String
  has_many    :feedposts
  embedded_in :user
end

class Feedpost
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title    => String
  field :text     => String
  field :resource => String
  field :time     => Time, :default => -> { Time.now }
  belongs_to  :feed
  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :user
  field   :text => String
  field   :time => Time, :default => -> { Time.now }
  embedded_in :feedpost
end
```

When trying to save a Feed (no Feedpost nor Comment implied), it just tells me that the method "new?" is not defined for NilClass.
I got this traceback from Rails :

```
activesupport (3.1.0.rc5) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/embedded/insert.rb:31:in `block in persist'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in prepare'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_create_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in prepare'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:24:in `block in prepare'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `tap'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `prepare'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/embedded/insert.rb:30:in `persist'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:44:in `insert'
mongoid (2.2.0) lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:149:in `upsert'
```

EDIT:
Here goes, this is the controller :

```
class FeedsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user  = CurrentUser()
    @feeds = @user.feeds
  end

  def create
    @feed   = Feed.new params[:feed]
    success = @feed.save # This is the line that trigger the error
    render json: { :success => success }
  end
end
```

And this is Mongoid's configuration :

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: noosphere_development
```

What the heck is happening to me ? Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: you may need to post more about your mongodb setup. Have you been able to store anything at all in it?

Comment: As mkro mentioned,  We need to see your controller code

Comment: Just to chime in here I dont think thats the full backtrace since it starts with code in activesupport. Can you post the whole thing trace and what line triggers the error?

Comment: The missing line in the backtrace is the nature of the exception (NoMethodError, undefined method `new?' for nil:NilClass), and is triggered by the controller line annoted with a comment. Thanks for helping, I think I've met the requirement :) !

Comment: Please post the params that you're sending to your controller.